# Spring MVC Error Messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring MVC Error Messages

Hello, Spring Fellows,

I have a form that is validated by the Spring Validation once submitted. Each field on the form may contain multiple errors messages if validation fails, so error messages are displayed below the field, not next to it. Here's the code snippet.

```
<tr>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:errors path="name*" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Note that there is a star at the end of the path value to indicate that all error messages for the `name` must be displayed.

As you can see, the problem is that, if there is no error message, there will be an extra row on the page that looks out of place to the user. The code above is an overly simplied version, so the actual code has a lot more stuff in it, which prevents me from moving the `<form:errors>` tag inside the  tag containing the field.

Is there a way to find out if there is any message associated to a given path on the JSP level? Basically, I would like to do the following:

```
<c:if test="${what do I write here?}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:errors path="name*" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:if>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this (notice that `bind` is from [`spring`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html) taglib):

```
<spring:bind path = "name*">
    <c:if test="${status.error}"> 
        <tr> 
            <td> 
                <form:errors path="name*" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </c:if> 
</spring:bind>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved your problem by doing this:

```
<table>
    <form:errors path="firstName">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <form:errors path="firstName"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form:errors>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstName"><spring:message code="helloworld.label.firstName"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

errors tag body will be evaluated only if there are errors on the path.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to not use tables for page layout. Utilizing div tags alleviates this problem altogether since divs are completely dimensionless if set to hidden.

Comment: I considered using <div>, but it has its own problem, which makes it impossible to set each column to the same width unless you know the longest pixel length of the texts in it during the rendering time.

Comment: That's why you put the divs inside a parent div. You can have the parent div resize with the largest encapslated div and the rest of the encapsulated divs flow within the parent based on your stylesheet.

Comment: Or wrap text inside nested divs and keep parent div static width.  I will submit, that if you don't adhere to w3c standards, IE has trouble version to version with consistency in handling heights and widths. So many hours wasted on this... if only enterprises defaulted to FF :).